# What is daily sedation interruption for ventilated patients?

Tags: nutrition, medications, infection, infectious-diseases, sedative-sedation

I was reading about ventilator bundle [here](https://www.chpso.org/sites/main/files/file-attachments/wip.pdf) and came across this term called `Daily Sedation Interruption`.

Does this term mean break in giving the sedation drugs?

How can this help in reducing the length of stay in icu?

Can someone help me understand what this term means and how it is useful in simple layman terms please? I am new to healthcare and from IT background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, daily sedation interruption means a break in giving the sedation therapy.

According to a 2014 Cochrane review: [Daily sedation interruption versus no daily sedation interruption for critically ill adult patients requiring invasive mechanical ventilation](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD009176.pub2/full):

> Daily sedation interruption (DSI) is thought to limit drug
>   bioaccumulation, promote a more awake state, and thereby reduce the
>   duration of mechanical ventilation. Available evidence has shown DSI
>   to either reduce, not alter, or prolong the duration of mechanical
>   ventilation.

But, according to their review of studies:

> We have not found strong evidence that DSI alters the duration of
>   mechanical ventilation, mortality, length of ICU or hospital stay,
>   adverse event rates, drug consumption, or quality of life for
>   critically ill adults receiving mechanical ventilation compared to
>   sedation strategies that do not include DSI.

Simply put: Daily sedation interruption is *intended* to shorten the ICU stay, but even if evidence from some studies has shown that it can reduce the duration of mechanical ventilation, the authors of the Cochrane's review have found *no evidence* that it shortens the ICU stay.

Here's an example of a controlled trial published in [JAMA, 2012](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/1380160), in which they have found the same results:

> For mechanically ventilated adults managed with protocolized sedation,
>   the addition of daily sedation interruption did not reduce the
>   duration of mechanical ventilation or ICU stay.

Comment: Hi Jan, can help me with this? https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/scoring-systems-and-different-mortality-definitions-for-liver-cirrhosis